# executing function in the handler

Tags: javascript

what difference does it make:

```
function a(){
//...
}

setInterval(a, 1000);
```

vs

```
setInterval(function(){
a();
}, 1000);
```

Except of the obvious that I can pass parameter in the second case.

It should not necessarily be setInterval. Any function that can accept function handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an anonymous function also allows you to call `someObject.a()` and preserve `this`.

If you write `setTimeout(someObject.a, 300)`, the `a()` method will be called in the context of the global object, so that its `this` would be `window`.  If it expects `this` to be `someObject`, it will break.

If you write `setTimeout(function() { someObject.a(); }, 300)`, `a()` will be called in the correct context.

Comment: Not only does it allow you to preserve `this`, but it allows you to pass parameters without hardcoding a string for the function call.

Comment: @ianpgall: Yes, but the OP already said that in the question.

Comment: @SLaks jeez, can't believe I didn't see that, thanks for pointing that out.